# Changing lowercase into upper case in real time in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

Basically, I am trying to get it so that when the user types in a lowercase letter, let's say "a", the screen will output an uppercase "A" instead. This is in flutter web using a keyboard. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Widget `TextFormField` have a propriety `textCapitalization`

Show you :

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
),
```

You have different proprieties like

```
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none, // Default
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextInputFormatter`

```dart
class UpperCaseFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return newValue.copyWith(text: newValue.text.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

And use like

```dart
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [ UpperCaseFormatter() ],
),
```